# Error using star as command line argument in script file

Tags: bash

When I try to execute my script `qwer.bash` like this:

```
bash qwer.bash *whatever #whatever can really be anything
```

it will give back to me:

```
qwer.bash: line 5: [[: *whatever: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*whatever")
```

here is my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    declare -a files

    while [[ "$1" -ne "-p" ]]
    do
            echo "pwet"
            shift
    done
```

How can I avoid producing this error?

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the test `$1 -ne ...` generates an error when`$1` is not an integer.

Try this:

```
while [[ "${#}" > 0 && "${1}" != "-p" ]]; do
    echo "pwet"
    shift
done
```

When `shift` is executed, `${#}` decrements.

When `"${#}" > 0` is false, the `while` loop ends. Note that `&&` instructs the shell to **not** evaluate the second operand (`"${1}" != "-p"`) when the first one is already false.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is irrelevant in your case

Regarding

```
bash qwer.bash *whatever #whatever can really be anything
```

**Case 1:** If `*whatever` is meant to glob files :

```
bash qwer.bash ./*whatever
```

or

```
bash qwer.bash -- *whatever # here -- marks the end of options
```

or

```
./qwer.bash -- *whatever # you already have a shebang in your script.
```

This is to handle a case where you actually have a  file named `-file-with-dash` in the current folder which may **wrongly** be taken as an option

**Case 2:** If `*whatever` is just a string:

```
bash qwer.bash \*whatever
```

or

```
bash qwer.bash "*whatever"
```

Comment: Interesting, so *whatever could include subdirectories? For example could it include then a/b/c/whatever if whatever was a file in such subdirectory a/b/c in the possible search options of grep?

Comment: `*whatever` will pick the `files/directories` that contains `whatever`. The format to look for sub-directories  is `./*whatever` for the first level and so on.